# Set Sphinx relevance ranking for RT index

Tags: sphinx

How do I include a ranking type (such as SPH_RANK_NONE) in a Sphinx RT query?

```
select id from my_index where match('hello') 
order by date
limit 600 ;
```

Also, is there a way to just set it once, for example, in the config file?

Sphinx doc:
http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2010/08/17/how-sphinx-relevance-ranking-works/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default ranking mode is `SPH_RANK_PROXIMITY_BM25` and it can't be changed using config.

This is how you set a ranking mode for a query (note that `ORDER BY` must have explicit `ASC`/`DESC` order clause):

```
SELECT id FROM my_index where MATCH('hello') 
     ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 600 OPTION ranker=sph04;
```

Relevant parts in the doc:

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#weighting
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinxql-select

Comment: Perfect, thanks! For SPH_RANK_NONE I used ranker=none. Made my queries faster :) No reason to use ranking when I'm sorting by date anyway.